# "Undefined reference to" error when trying to link external (OpenGL) libraries with g++

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors, g++, undefined-reference

I am trying to build two c++ files. These include the GLFW and GLEW libraries, as I'm trying to write OpenGL code. App.cpp is the main file, and loadShader.cpp is the implementation file of loadShader.h.
The Libraries and Include folders are in another folder called "Imports"

I am using Mingw32 as my compiler and vscode as my code editor.

In the integrated terminal I tried running the following command:
`Working directory> g++ -O2 -Wall -o OpenGL "src/App.cpp" "src/header files/loadShader.cpp" -I "Imports/GLEW/include" -I "Imports/GLFW/include" -I "Imports/glm" -L "Imports/GLEW/lib/Release/Win32" -L "Imports/GLFW/lib-vc2022"`
When I run the command, it doesn't give me any errors about not finding the libraries or include files/folders specified. It only gives me the error after it starts trying to compile App.cpp and loadShader.cpp

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1e): undefined reference to `_imp__glewExperimental' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x26): undefined reference to` glfwInit'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x42): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x56): undefined reference to` glfwWindowHint'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x6a): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x7e): undefined reference to` glfwWindowHint'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x92): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0xbe): undefined reference to` glfwCreateWindow'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd0): undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0xd9): undefined reference to` _imp__glewInit@0'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0xff): undefined reference to `_imp____glewGenVertexArrays' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x112): undefined reference to` _imp____glewBindVertexArray'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x12f): undefined reference to `glfwSetInputMode' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2d6): undefined reference to` _imp____glewGetUniformLocation'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x2f7): undefined reference to `_imp____glewGenBuffers' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x305): undefined reference to` _imp____glewBindBuffer'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x31b): undefined reference to `_imp____glewBufferData' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x355): undefined reference to` _imp____glewGenBuffers'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3af): undefined reference to `glClearColor@16' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3b5): undefined reference to` _imp____glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3c4): undefined reference to `glClear@4' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x3d5): undefined reference to` _imp____glewUseProgram'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x402): undefined reference to `_imp____glewUniformMatrix4fv' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x428): undefined reference to` _imp____glewVertexAttribPointer'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x483): undefined reference to `_imp____glewVertexAttribPointer' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4c6): undefined reference to` glEnable@4'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4d5): undefined reference to `glDepthFunc@4' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4f4): undefined reference to` glDrawArrays@12'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x4f9): undefined reference to `_imp____glewDisableVertexAttribArray' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x50a): undefined reference to` _imp____glewDisableVertexAttribArray'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x521): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x526): undefined reference to` glfwPollEvents'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x536): undefined reference to `glfwGetKey' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x543): undefined reference to` glfwWindowShouldClose'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x551): undefined reference to `_imp____glewDeleteBuffers' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x588): undefined reference to` _imp____glewDeleteProgram'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x5a3): undefined reference to `_imp____glewDeleteVertexArrays' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x5ad): undefined reference to` glfwTerminate'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc3hmk5n.o:App.cpp:(.text.startup+0x642): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to` _imp____glewCreateShader'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xc72): undefined reference to `_imp____glewShaderSource' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xc79): undefined reference to` _imp____glewCompileShader'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xc87): undefined reference to `_imp____glewGetShaderiv' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xd27): undefined reference to` _imp____glewGetShaderInfoLog'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xd87): undefined reference to `_imp____glewShaderSource' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xd8e): undefined reference to` _imp____glewCompileShader'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xe24): undefined reference to `_imp____glewGetShaderInfoLog' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xe4e): undefined reference to` _imp____glewCreateProgram'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xe58): undefined reference to `_imp____glewAttachShader' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xe7e): undefined reference to` _imp____glewLinkProgram'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xe8c): undefined reference to `_imp____glewGetProgramiv' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xeff): undefined reference to` _imp____glewGetProgramInfoLog'
> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xf33): undefined reference to `_imp____glewDetachShader' C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cclIYxso.o:loadShader.cpp:(.text+0xf54): undefined reference to` _imp____glewDeleteShader'
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You didn't actually specify any libraries to link. `-L` is only for the path to the directory containing libraries. The individual library files should be specified with `-l` flags, without file ending and without a `lib` prefix, e.g. `-lglfw`, probably also `-lglew` and `-lgl`. The order of these flags may be significant.

Comment: I tried to use the ```-l``` flag but it says it cannot find the file (in this case glfw). Originally, instead of the -L, I put -l, and after seeing it couldn't find it, I changed it to -L (thinking that they are the same). So how would I fix the issue of -l giving me the error of not finding the library?

Comment: You need to figure out where the glfw library file is located, add the path to that file as `-L` argument and then add the `-lglfw` flag after that `-L` flag.

Comment: Oh sorry, I think I misunderstood at first. So the -L flag is simply to specify where Libraries may be found, and the -l is actually linking those libraries, by checking at the places where we said they might be using -L, right? Using the files inside the library files without the lib prefix and file ending, it gave me new errors.

Comment: Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
A lot of these and then many others that are very similar to the ones I posted originally

Comment: @Azukitsu It sounds like you've linked with the wrong library. Do you have `pkg-config` installed?

Comment: The naming of the path `lib-vc2022` seems to indicate that you downloaded/installed the library for Visual Studio/Visual C++ (vc). You should be using libraries compiled for MinGW.

Comment: @user17732522 Yeah I just noticed as well, so I tried changing the lib files to the mingw version, but it still gives me errors

Comment: @TedLyngmo I don't have it installed, but It's possible that it is the wrong library